# How to display much text on the command window?

Tags: matlab

I need to print a text with more lines on the command window.

example:

```
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Normally I use `display('Text')`

But that is not the best way, isn't it?

Note:
I tried this

```
fprintf(1, ...
'wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww '...
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa '...
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa '...
 );
```

So my question is:

**How to display much text on the command window?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add some formatting to your string, just use `fprintf` with the format specifier:

```
fprintf('%s\n%s\n%s\n',...
    'wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww',...
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',...
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
```

Read the [documenttion](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to learn more.

Note that the `1` as a first argument may be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `fprintf(1,...)` as file descriptor 1 is the command window in IDE mode

Comment: If you mean you want to print long rows of the same character, as in your example, you can use code like `fprintf(1, '%c', repmat('a', 1, 20)); fprintf(1, '\n')`

Comment: No I want to print a text. Like a description of some thing

Comment: Where does the text come from? Is it in a Matlab string variable? Doe it contain the newlines as well?

Comment: No it doesn't contain them. So I think I have to insert them

Comment: Yes, you will need to include the `\n` escape character each time you want a new line. If you just have fixed text, the text and the newlines can go in the format string: if the text comes from one or more variables, you will need to include the newlines in the text  variables where you need them.